# Conflict management during file operations

Tags: filemanager

When you copy files from A to B and there are conflicts, you have to wait until the conflict arises before you can make a decision on it (merge, replace, etc.). If you're copying several gb's or even tb's of data this can mean a huge wait time before you ever see a file conflict pop up (think 3 hours into 8 hour transfer), at that point you can select merge -> do this for all conflicts of this type. When I do a massive transfer I would like to set it and forget it. As it is, you need to constantly check in on progress.

As soon as I begin copying I would like to see a list of conflict types where I can select what I want to do.
i.e. file transfer begins, I select merge all folders, skip all files.

Is there a way to get this to happen? If not how can I submit this suggestion to Ubuntu developers?

Comment: In Ubuntu suggestions for improvements are filed as wishlist bugs against the package that would be improved. If I understand correctly Ubuntu is going to a new file manager that uses qt. I believe the right place for such a wishlist item is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-filemanager-app . See https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2014-January/004414.html. The current file manager is called Nautilus. Its bugs are filed at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you could simply create a file with the same name in both directories before starting the copy. If you name this file something like `aaaaaa`, the conflict will arise very early in the copying process and you will be presented with the conflict resolution dialogue early.

This is neither elegant nor a solution as such but it should serve as a workaround.